get stats of tg channel
There is a need to get the number of channel subscribers in a telegram over time.
I tried to use tdlib, had difficulty installing it, but then difficulties arose. I use python, I managed to connect tdlib and log in.
I use.
print(td_send({'@type':'getChat', 'chat_id':-11231231231, 'extra':1001011}))

function td_send was taken from example
def td_send(query):

    query = json.dumps(query).encode('utf-8')
    # enter code here
    _td_send(client_id, query)

it returns None
chat_id is random there
Tell me, please, at least schematically
what am I doing wrong, what needs to be added in order to get the number of subscribers for a certain period.
I've spent several evenings working on this
if it doesn’t work with tdlib, then the only idea is to periodically record the number of subscribers using the same teletho

Don't you need to provide the correct chat id, instead of random?
